# Error Code:1 (SQLITE_ERROR) Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database

Tags: java, android

This is my Database Helper class   and I getting Error This is y console

"  Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database. (no such table: profile (code 1): , while compiling: select * from profile where id_profile=6)     "
  Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database. (no such table: profile (code 1): , while compiling: select * from profile where id_profile=6)
  Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database. (no such table: profile (code 1): , while compiling: select * from profile where id_profile=6)
  Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database. (no such table: profile (code 1): , while compiling: select * from profile where id_profile=6)
  Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database. (no such table: profile (code 1): , while compiling: select * from profile where id_profile=6)
  Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database. (no such table: profile (code 1): , while compiling: select * from profile where id_profile=6)       Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database. (no such table: profile (code 1): , while compiling: select * from profile where id_profile=6)       Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database. (no such table: profile (code 1): , while compiling: select * from profile where id_profile=6)
  Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database. (no such table: profile (code 1): , while compiling: select * from profile where id_profile=6)       Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database. (no such table: profile (code 1): , while compiling: select * from profile where id_profile=6)

Anyone PLease Help

```js
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {



    private static String DB_NAME = "ocinator.db";
    private static String DB_PATH = "";
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 8;

    private SQLiteDatabase mDataBase;
    private final Context mContext;
    private boolean mNeedUpdate = false;

static final String PROFILE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE profile (" +
        "    id_profile      INTEGER      PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
        "    first_name      VARCHAR (15)," +
        "    last_name       VARCHAR (15)," +
        "    email           VARCHAR (50)," +
        "    phone           VARCHAR (30)," +
        "    login_status    VARCHAR (20)," +
        "    username        VARCHAR (30)," +
        "    password        TEXT," +
        "    ocinator_id     DOUBLE," +
        "    name            VARCHAR (39)," +
        "    nickname        VARCHAR (30)," +
        "    registered_date DATETIME" +
        ");";


    static final String NOTIFICATIONS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE notification_oc (" +
            "    notification_id           INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
            "    notification_title        TEXT," +
            "    notification_message      TEXT," +
            "    notification_firetime     DATETIME," +
            "    notification_creationtime DATETIME DEFAULT (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)," +
            "    notification_status       TEXT" +
            ");" ;



    /**
     * Constructor
     * Takes and keeps a reference of the passed context in order to access to the application assets and resources.
     * @param context
     */
    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17)
            DB_PATH = context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/databases/";
        else
            DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases/";
        this.mContext = context;

        copyDataBase();

        this.getReadableDatabase();
    }

    public void updateDataBase() throws IOException {
        if (mNeedUpdate) {
            File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
            if (dbFile.exists())
                dbFile.delete();

            copyDataBase();

            mNeedUpdate = false;
        }
    }

    private boolean checkDataBase() {
        File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
        return dbFile.exists();
    }

    private void copyDataBase() {
        if (!checkDataBase()) {
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            this.close();
            try {
                copyDBFile();
            } catch (IOException mIOException) {
                throw new Error("ErrorCopyingDataBase");
            }
        }
    }



    private void copyDBFile() throws IOException {

        System.out.println("Input xx started");
        InputStream mInput = mContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
        //InputStream mInput = mContext.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.info);
        OutputStream mOutput = new FileOutputStream(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
        byte[] mBuffer = new byte[1024];
        int mLength;
        while ((mLength = mInput.read(mBuffer)) > 0)
            mOutput.write(mBuffer, 0, mLength);
        mOutput.flush();
        mOutput.close();
        mInput.close();
    }

    public boolean openDataBase() throws SQLException {
        mDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_PATH + DB_NAME, null, SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY);
        return mDataBase != null;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {
        if (mDataBase != null)
            mDataBase.close();
        super.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

     //   db.execSQL(PROFILE_TABLE);
     //   db.execSQL(NOTIFICATIONS_TABLE);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        if (newVersion > oldVersion)
            mNeedUpdate = true;

       // db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS profile");
       // db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS notification_oc");
       // onCreate(db);

    }




    public boolean insertNotification (String title, String msg, String time, String status) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("notification_title", title);
        contentValues.put("notification_message", msg);
        contentValues.put("notification_firetime", time);
        contentValues.put("notification_status", status);
        db.insert("notification_oc", null, contentValues);
        return true;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getAllNotifications() {
        ArrayList<String> array_list = new ArrayList<String>();

        //hp = new HashMap();
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select * from notification_oc", null );
        res.moveToFirst();

        while(res.isAfterLast() == false){
            array_list.add(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("notification_title")));
            res.moveToNext();
        }
        return array_list;
    }

    public Cursor getNotification(int id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select * from notification_oc where notification_id="+id+"", null );
        return res;
    }

    public int numberOfRowsInNotifications(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        int numRows = (int) DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db, "notification_oc");
        return numRows;
    }


    public Integer deleteNotification (Integer id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        return db.delete("notification_oc",
                "notification_id = ? ",
                new String[] { Integer.toString(id) });
    }




    public boolean insertUser (String username, String password, String nickname, String email) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("username", username);
        contentValues.put("password", password);
        contentValues.put("nickname", nickname);
        contentValues.put("email", email);
        db.insert("profile", null, contentValues);
        return true;
    }


    public Integer deleteUser (Integer id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        return db.delete("profile",
                "id_profile = ? ",
                new String[] { Integer.toString(id) });
    }

    public Cursor getUser(int id) {

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        System.out.println("USERNAMEX1 : 111" );
        Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select * from profile where id_profile="+id+"", null );
        System.out.println("USERNAMEX2 : 222" );
        return res;
    }

    // Add your public helper methods to access and get content from the database.
    // You could return cursors by doing "return myDataBase.query(....)" so it'd be easy
    // to you to create adapters for your views.

}
```

Comment: What is db version in the file you copy? is it same as 8?

Comment: Yes it is same but I have also tried after change it

Answer (score 0):

You are using this for the database dir:

```
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17)
        DB_PATH = context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/databases/";
    else
        DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases/";
```

and then

```
    DB_PATH + DB_NAME
```

You should use this as copy destination.

```
    context.getDatabasePath() + "/" + DB_NAME
```

It seems problem is you copied to somewhere which is not dir for SQLiteOpenHelper. Though mDatabase is used to open the file after you copy, it is not what SQLiteOpenHelper will use, and SQLiteOpenHelper will use its own for getReadableDatabase and getWritableDatabase, which is not the copied one, and it does not have the table you want.